# Why is DBMS Scheduler changing database session language?

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I have LEVSTAT_PLNGRP procedure that needs to be called at certain time and in response it makes an entry in one of the DB table.

Initially `select VALUE from V$NLS_PARAMETERS;` query returns `SWEDISH` as output.

when I run LEVSTAT_PLNGRP procedure manually, it makes correct data entry in respective table and `select VALUE from V$NLS_PARAMETERS;` query returns `SWEDISH` as output after the run.

But when I try to run LEVSTAT_PLNGRP procedure via DBMS Scheduler, it fails to make entry in the table and `select VALUE from V$NLS_PARAMETERS;` query returns `ENGLISH` as output after the run.

Does DBMS scheduler change the language of the DB session or is there a default parameter set somewhere?

Comment: The underlying problem is that your PL/SQL makes assumptions about the current NLS language - why is it doing that? And what exactly is the code that fails? (**[edit]** your question, do not post code in comments)

Answer (score 1):

DBMS_SCHEDULER uses the NLS settings of the session that *created* the job.  Which may not be the same as the NLS settings of the session that created the procedure.

For example, my session default NLS_LANGUAGE is ENGLISH:

```
SQL> declare a number; begin a := 1/0; end;
  2  /
declare a number; begin a := 1/0; end;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

If I change it to Swedish and create the job it runs with Swedish:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_language = 'Swedish';

Session ar andrad.

SQL> begin
  2     dbms_scheduler.create_job(
  3             job_name => 'TEST_JOB1',
  4             job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5             job_action => 'declare a number; begin a := 1/0; end;',
  6             enabled => true
  7     );
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL-procedur har utforts.

SQL> select errors from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name = 'TEST_JOB1';

ERRORS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORA-01476: division med noll
ORA-06512: vid rad 1

SQL>
```

**But programs should never fail because of NLS settings.**  PL/SQL code should never make assumptions about client settings.  If something must be done in a specific language, avoid all implicit conversions and hard-code that language in the code.